# Mongoose find callback function executing both if and else statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose and Node, but this is the route for my page for showing one campground. For some reason, the callback function for findById is running both if and else statements below. **So my code works in finding the correct object and displaying it in the browser, but it also seems to be returning an undefined object.**

Also, when I console.log(camp.name) in the callback function, it throws an error and says that it cannot reference the name property of undefined...so it seems to be referencing some undefined object even though it did find the object i'm looking for.

```
app.get("/campgrounds/:id",function(req, res){
    var camp_Id = req.params.id;
    console.log("ID type: "+ typeof(camp_Id) + " | "+camp_Id);

    var camps = Campground.findById(camp_Id, function(err,camp){
        console.log(camp);

        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.render("show", {camp:camp});
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the console output:

```
ID type: string | 5a80c8c54d30a717de9121f4
{ _id: 5a80c8c54d30a717de9121f4,
  name: 'Fire Camp',
  image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496379590766-6732d042fef5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=65f8c4aa65a833e229c48dd9d3c2f12d&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80',
  description: 'Fire and Camps and stuff. Best for smores.',
  __v: 0 }
ID type: string | campgrounds.js
undefined
{ CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "campgrounds.js" at path "_id" for model "Campground"
    at MongooseError.CastError (/home/ec2-user/environment/YelpCamp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:27:11)
    at ObjectId.cast (/home/ec2-user/environment/YelpCamp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:158:13)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (/home/ec2-user/environment/YelpCamp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:701:12)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (/home/ec2-user/environment/YelpCamp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1072:15)
    at ObjectId.castForQuery (/home/ec2-user/environment/YelpCamp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:198:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (/home/ec2-user/environment/YelpCamp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1041:15)
    at cast (/home/ec2-user/environment/YelpCamp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:273:32)
    at Query.cast (/home/ec2-user/environment/YelpCamp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3133:12)
    at Query._castConditions (/home/ec2-user/environment/YelpCamp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1269:10)
    at Query._findOne (/home/ec2-user/environment/YelpCamp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1485:8)
    at /home/ec2-user/environment/YelpCamp/node_modules/kareem/index.js:276:8
    at /home/ec2-user/environment/YelpCamp/node_modules/kareem/index.js:23:7
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "campgrounds.js" at path "_id" for model "Campground"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"campgrounds.js"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'campgrounds.js',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined,
  model: 
   { [Function: model]
     hooks: Kareem { _pres: [Object], _posts: [Object] },
     base: 
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
        plugins: [Object] },
     modelName: 'Campground',
     model: [Function: model],
     db: 
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: null,
        pass: null,
        name: 'YelpCamp',
        options: null,
        otherDbs: [],
        states: [Object],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        _listening: false,
        _connectionOptions: [Object],
        '$initialConnection': [Object],
        db: [Object],
        client: [Object] },
     discriminators: undefined,
     '$appliedMethods': true,
     '$appliedHooks': true,
     schema: 
      Schema {
        obj: [Object],
        paths: [Object],
        aliases: {},
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        singleNestedPaths: {},
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        query: {},
        childSchemas: [],
        plugins: [Object],
        s: [Object],
        _userProvidedOptions: undefined,
        options: [Object],
        '$globalPluginsApplied': true,
        _requiredpaths: [] },
     collection: 
      NativeCollection {
        collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'campgrounds',
        collectionName: 'campgrounds',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false,
        emitter: [Object] },
     Query: { [Function] base: [Object] },
     '$__insertMany': [Function],
     '$init': Promise { [Object], catch: [Function] } } }
```

EDIT: Here is the code from the my view: campgrounds.ejs:

```
<% for(var i=0; i < camps.length; i++){     %>

            <div class = "col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="/campgrounds/<%=camps[i].id%>">
                <div class = "img-thumbnail">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="<%=camps[i]["image"]%>" alt="<%=camps[i]["name"]%>">
                    <div class="caption text-center"><%= camps[i]["name"] %></div>
                </div>
                </a>
            </div>

        <%    };    %>
```

Comment: Look in your developer tools network tab for campgrounds.js and check the initiator column. I guess you either have a `<script src=` or make a ajax request to it.

Comment: Yep, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is probably in your view, just look at the second log for the id:

`ID type: string | campgrounds.js`,

After that mongoose tells you it failed when the id was **campground.js**:

`'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "campgrounds.js" at path "_id"`

You are probably making a call to your route with **campgrounds.js** as the id.

Comment: hmm...not sure how I am doing that. I've added the view code on my original question. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Are you sure there is no other call to your route being made when clicking on the camp link? Maybe in a jQuery script there's an event listener for the `image-thumbnail` div or something like that

Comment: Yea you are right. I included a script tag directing to campgrounds.js in my footer file. But the eventListener in that file was only suppose to reference an ID that's on a previous page....In any case, when I removed it worked.

Comment: Well if the script tag src points to: `/campgrounds/campground.js` then the call is being made when the browser loads the file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are making two requests, one to "/campgrounds/5a80c8c54d30a717de9121f4" that find the correct object, and an other one to "/campgrounds/campgrounds.js" that returns undefined.

Comment: Yeah, the error is probably in the view, when making the ajax call or smtg

Comment: hmm...not sure how I am doing that. I've added the view code on my original question. Could you please take a look?

Comment: In the camps array, do you have any camps[i].id with a 'compground.js' value?

Answer (score 0):

This should be changed from

```
Campground.findById(camp_Id, function(err,camp){
```

to

```
Campground.findById(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(camp_Id), function(err,camp){
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to pass :id in this route. If you have a route something like "campgrounds/xyz" and that is placed under the "campgrounds/:id" route. Then it will treat "xyz" as :id and try to render this page.

Try placing "campgroungs/:id" route code snippet under all other routes and check